# Air 3 for Mobile - StageText example?

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air

Air 3 for mobile introduces a nice feature - StageText. I have seen a few videos showing what the end result looks like, but I cannot find how to actually implement it in code.

[There is this page here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/StageText), however, when trying to add the extra properties to the s:TextInput elements, I only get errors. Obviously, something is missing.

Anyone out there have any hints or working examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of the Flex SDK are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new `TextInput` enhancements are part of the [Flex 4.6 SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/whats-new-flex-flash-builder-46.html) which has not been released yet (as of 11/3/2011).  If you want access to it right now, you need to sign up for the [pre-release program](https://prerelease.adobe.com/callout/default.html?callid=DC919522A42544798C33ECB4041FC5DC).

Comment: Bah. Didn't realize that from anything that I read. Everything I saw must have been using 4.6 and just didn't say it.

Comment: Update:  Flex 4.6 is available now.